# Process duplicate field values

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I am using SQLite 3.11. I create a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (F1 INTEGER, F2 INTEGER);
```

Then add the following records:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (1, 2); 
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (1, 3);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (2, 4);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (2, 5);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (3, 6);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (3, 7);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2) Values (4, 2);
```

Now if two records have the same value of F1, then I will define them as conflict records.

Now I need to perform the following tasks:

1. For all conflict records, get the total count of distinct F1 values. In the above sample, record 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 are conflict records, but the distinct values are only 1, 2, 3 so the total count should be 3.
2. Get the total count of conflict records. In the above sample, it should be 6.
3. Set the F2 value of the conflict records to 9. Keep all other records intact.

How to do that? Can task 2 and 3 be implemented in one SQL query to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for conflicts, group by `F1`, and the look at groups with more than onw row.

The count of distinct values is just the number of such groups:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT F1
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY F1
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

(Note: the two `COUNT(*)` count different things.)

The number of conflict records is the number of rows in the table with such a `F1` value:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE F1 IN (SELECT F1
             FROM MyTable
             GROUP BY F1
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Updating them uses the same mechanism:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET F2 = 9
WHERE F1 IN (SELECT F1
             FROM MyTable
             GROUP BY F1
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Using one query is not possible, and would not improve the performance anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer!